# default datetime value is shown in datatable for random records in a datetime column even when I am not assigning the value anywhere

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable, parallel-processing, locking

I have a `DataTable` in which I am adding some extra columns with `DateTime` datatype.

Just like this:    `MyTable.Columns.Add("myDate",typeof(DateTime));`

I am not assigning any value to this column. I am just adding a new row to MyTable as below:

```
DataRow dr=null;
dr=MyTable.NewRow();
dr["Name"]= "abc";//updating all the columns except datetime column in the same way.

lock(MyTable)//locking dt as this code is part of  
Parallel.ForEach
{
   MyTable.Rows.Add(dr);
   MyTable.AcceptChanges();
}
```

After the above `Parallel.ForEach` loop completed when I check the values of DateTime column then it shows value **'01-01-0001 12:00:00 AM'** for random records.

- Each time I run my code this *default DateTime value* is shown for different records.
- Sometimes this value is *null* for all the records.

I am not able to understand, why the default value is shown in my Date column.
Even when I am not setting anything into these cells, the values are not same for   each cell.

Please help me to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Is the column a nullable `DateTime`? `default(DateTime)` is `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Yes, It is nullable.

Answer (score 0):

The ADO.NET classes are [not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155180/which-ado-net-dataset-datatable-methods-are-safe-for-multiple-reader-threads) for multithreaded **write** operations. It is simply not allowed to use the `Parallel.ForEach` in order to update a `DataTable` from multiple threads in parallel, without synchronization. If you do it, the outcome is undefined. You may get exceptions, lose data, get corrupted data, get a corrupted internal state, whatever. No one knows what will happen exactly, but the probabilities that the outcome will be desirable are minuscule.

Comment: Can we use object of WCF datacontract instead of datatable?

Comment: @Vidhi unfortunately I don't know much about Data Contracts.