# How to compare two DataTables and update the first DataTable using multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable, console-application, multitasking

In table 1 there are 150,000 records, I have to compare each record from table 1 one by one with corresponding record in table 2, if match is found update the same record in table 1, if match is not found need to update `Notes` column value in table 1 to no matching record found.

For this I am fetching records from both tables in `dt` and `dt1` respectively.

Following is the code I have done

```
DataTable dt = getRecordsfromTable1();
DataTable dt1 = getRecordsfromTable2();
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
     foreach(DataRow dr1 in dt1.Rows)
     {
          if(dr["Id"].ToString() == dr1["Id"].ToString())
          {
               //Calling update method in Data Access Layer to Update record in First table
               Update(dr["Id"].ToString());
          }
          else
         {
             //Id not found
         }
     }
}
```

But this is working very slow as I am comparing 150,000 records one by one. How to use multithreading concept over here to make processing faster?

Comment: better use methods that are _specially optimised_ for this kind of thing. your code is extremely inefficient and has O(n^2) complexity - no amount of multithreading will _significantly_ speed this up. have a look at [Enumerable.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-5.0) instead (also: your call to `ToString()` on the ids seems to be superfluous, most likely)

Comment: Multithreading is useful for CPU intensive computations. It's not good for IO.

Comment: This task is better done by MERGE SQL statement.

Comment: Comparing 150,000 records **is something that should not be done in C#** because it is not designed for this type of workload. Databases, on the other hand, explicitly are. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: `150000` that's not a lot of records. The database can already do what you ask *far faster* than any client because it can use indexes and has far faster CPU, RAM and disks than any client. As in orders of magnitude faster (1000, 10K, 100K)

Comment: `MERGE` isn't a good idea here. A *fast* way is to insert all the records into a staging table with SqlBulkCopy then execute an `UPDATE final .... from final inner join staging on final.ID=staging.ID`. The join fields should be indexed

Comment: as a rule of thumb, parallelization should be used when all other optimizations are exhausted. Parallelization may give 2-20 times speedup, if you are lucky, while going from O(n^2) to O(n log n) can give speedup of many magnitudes more.

Comment: This should be done in SQL, not C#.

Comment: 150.000 entries is not that much, with Entityframework this should not be a problem.

Comment: FYI the ADO.NET classes [are not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155180/which-ado-net-dataset-datatable-methods-are-safe-for-multiple-reader-threads) for multithreaded **write** operations. So if you use multiple threads you'll have to add thread-synchronization, which is likely to negate most of the benefits of the parallelization.

Comment: What can be done to make this process faster? Can not use sql stored procedures as per requirement given. Have to write sql queries in c sharp

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to try here would be indexing on the `Id`, i.e.

```cs
Dictionary<string, DataRow> lookup = new();
// index dt1
foreach(DataRow dr1 in dt1.Rows)
{
    var id = dr1["Id"].ToString();
    lookup.Add(id, dr1);
}
// now enumerate dt
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    var id = dr["Id"].ToString();
    if (lookup.TryGetValue(id, out var dr1))
    {
        //Calling update method in Data Access Layer to Update record in First table
        Update(id);
    }
}
```

Note: if the `dr1` isn't actually needed for the `Update`, you could also potentially replace the `Dictionary<string, DataRow>` with just a `HashSet<string>` of the known ids.

As for parallelizing it: that depends an awful lot on what `Update` does; it may or may not be useful to parallelize. Happy to discuss more, but: would need to see it. If it is trivially parallelizable, then it *may* be sufficient to simply use:

```cs
// now enumerate dt concurrently
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), dr =>
{
    var id = dr["Id"].ToString();
    if (lookup.TryGetValue(id, out var dr1))
    {
        //Calling update method in Data Access Layer to Update record in First table
        Update(id);
    }
});
```

However, must database-related code is *not* trivially parallelizable.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach is not working giving error. System.AggregateException,The connection was not closed,connection's current state is connecting

Comment: I tried foreach but it took 4 hours to complete the process