# Multi-Threading on C# Dataset table rows making an external API call and update table with API Call results

Tags: c#, multithreading, stripe-payments, sqldatasource

I have a table in my SQL server/DB with close to 100,000 records. Using C# - need to loop thru the rows and make an external API call and update the results of the call into SQL table. I am new to multi-threading concept. How can I achieve this?

Here is the code I have - just sequential processing.

```
        public void MainProcess()
        {
            try
            {
                // Retrieve rows from table
                List<rowResult> rowResults = (List<rowResult>)GetRowsFromTable();
                foreach (var row in rowResults)
                {
                    callExternalAPI(row);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
         }
```

How can I modify this to enable Multi-threading? Please help

Comment: Regarding the `callExternalAPI(row)` call, is this method changing the `DataRow` object in any way, or is it changing the `DataTable`/`DataSet` that owns this `DataRow`? Be aware that ADO.NET classes [are not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155180/which-ado-net-dataset-datatable-methods-are-safe-for-multiple-reader-threads) for multithreaded write operations.

Comment: Based on the externalAPI results, the row changes the DataTable/DataSet and the table row gets updated in SQL Table. SInce you are saying ADO.Net classes are not safe for multithreaded write operations, what do you suggest @TheodorZoulias? Pl advise

Comment: Vambat if the `DataTable`/`DataSet` is mutable, you must ensure that only one thread can interact with it at a time. Every interaction (both read and write) must be protected with the `lock` statement, using the same locker object.

Comment: Sorry. Are you saying that "One thread should do the API Call, lock the row and update row? All the 3 steps should happen under the same thread?

Comment: I am concerned about the time it takes - for 100,000 API calls to Stripe API and update the table row.

Comment: Vambat no, it doesn't have to be the same thread. Multiple threads can interact with the ADO.NET objects, but one thread at a time. While a thread interacts with the `DataSet`, the other threads should either do other unrelated things, or wait for their turn to interact with the `DataSet`.

Comment: Hi @TheodorZoulias - Another question. Can you please help?. Inside the Parallel.ForEach loop - I have a try Catch block to capture any error. how can I do the continue - in case of an error to go back to the next row? It looks like there is no continue inside Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: I modified code - in the catch to check the error and go back to starting of the loop again. Looks like it works, Thanks

Comment: Vambat I am not sure that I understand what you ask. If you want to not stop a parallel loop, then simply don't `throw` inside the `catch`. If you mean something else, I would suggest to post a new question that includes a simple example demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach), replace your `foreach` with the below which calls `callExternalApi` directly with the `rowResult`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(rowResults, callExternalAPI);
```

Or if you need to do additional processing with each row you can use:

```
Parallel.ForEach(rowResults, row =>
{
    //Additional processing
    callExternalAPI(row);
    //Additional processing
});
```

You can also use [`ParallelOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions) to set how many threads are used with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`; though this should default to something sensible.

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
};
Parallel.ForEach(rowResults, po, callExternalAPI);
```

Comment: The default `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` for the `Parallel.ForEach` method is -1, which means unlimited parallelism. This is not sensible, but Microsoft [thinks otherwise](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72981#issuecomment-1198200618 "ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism documentation, is the given advice correct? - Stephen Toub commented on Jul 28, 2022").

Comment: Thanks a million for your quick response. I am going to try it and let you know. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I've had a look around in the source and and for [`TSource[]`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,1929) and [`IList<TSource>`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,1938) it will use `Environment.ProcessorCount` [link](https://source.dot.net/#System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,961) if `EffectiveMaxConcurrencyLevel` (which is derived from `MaxDegreeOfParallelism `) is `-1`. For anything else it looks like it will just use `Int.MaxValue`.

Comment: So best practice would be to always set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount`.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is to configure always the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, either with `Environment.ProcessorCount` (if you don't know a better value), or with a specific value that you came up after experimentation or after reading the specs of the remote service, or with -1 if you really want to saturate the `ThreadPool` for some reason.